# Link color animations broken on Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With Safari 5.1.4 on Mac OS 10.7.3, the color transitions for question links already visited (from  orange to black to gray) appear broken, in that they do not behave consistently.

Namely, if I move my mouse slowly over a link, then move it out, it does orange → black → gray, then gray → orange on hover-out. On the other hand, if I move faster, the links ends up black and does not turn back to orange.

Comment: You may have better luck posting [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126185/151611).

Comment: I may have to take the transition effect off for now. There's a known webkit bug that for visited links, it ignores the CSS3 transition effect.

Comment: @rcollyer thanks for the hint, I've [done so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme/126938#126938).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed the transition effect since it's causing problems on visited links in webkit browsers. The change will be in the next prod build.